# Does creating new object for Retrofit slows the service response time?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have used retrofit creating new objects each time I use a webservice . The webservice response time is good . But when tried within the app it slows down.

Does this effect the response?

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiConstants.BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(new ErrorCallback.ErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: It affects your memory usage.  You should be reusing the Retrofit instance.

Comment: ok thanks. But would this anyways effect the webservice response. As my TL told me it creates a new connection everytime new instance is made and handshake is done that make it delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Retrofit documentation the build, baseUrl, addCallAdapterFactory, addConverterFactory operations dont entablish any connections. This make sense because they are used just to prepare the Retrofit instance for communication.

Also, considering that restful servicies typically use HTTP for communication, there is no need to entablish a connection per session. The connection entablishes every time you call an operation of the webservice api.

So, creating the instance everytime will no affect in terms of communication, but it will affect the client cpu and memory resources unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new Retrofit instance does affect the response time and I can confirm this by my own recent experience. If I created new instance for each request the response time that I was getting was >= 1700ms where as when I used single instance for API calls, I got response in <= 500 ms.